# While Loading my site on the client's web page there occurs css property clash issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When i load my Website in the client's url, there occurs a error which takes the css property from the client's css and changed in our css which affects my site.

Is there is any way to write all the property and value in my class so that it will not take from the client's css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases where both stylesheets style the same properties but the wrong stylesheet is winning out (e.g. you have `p {border: 1px solid green; color: blue}` and the client css has `p {border: 1px solid red}` and the tables are getting a red border):

- If possible, tweak your css to avoid the conflict. This may also require tweaking your markup. For example, if your css and the client's css provides styles for a class called `.myclass`, you could rename yours to `.mynewclass`.
- You may also be able to get around this by increasing the specificity of your styles. For example, if `.myclass` is styled in the client css, your css could style `body .myclass`. For more on specificity, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
- There's always `!important` (e.g. `.myclass {border-color: green !important}`) which may make your styles win over the client's. Keep in mind that using a lot of `!important` is generally considered a sign of bad CSS.

---

In cases where the client stylesheet is styling a property you want left at the default (e.g. you want borderless `div`s, but the client css specifies `p {border: 1px solid red}`) you'll have to add an override: `p {border: 0;}`.

If you can wrap all your markup in an overriding class, you can do something like

```css
/* client's styles */
p {
  border: 1px solid blue
}
/* your styles */
.reset p {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>client (border)</p>
<div class="reset">
  <p>you (no border)</p>
</div>
```

Or maybe everything you add to the site is always inside the same element, like `.main`. In that case, in the above example you could style `.main p`.

If using a wrapper won't work, you can always add a reset class to every one of your elements. That will be a hassle, but it'll work:

```css
/* client's styles */
p {
  border: 1px solid blue
}
/* your styles */
p.reset {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>client (border)</p>
<p class="reset">you (no border)</p>
```

If you do a bunch of work with this client, it could be worth developing a "reset.css" with all your reset rules.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but for example I had a table and added a class called .mytable and applying some css properties to that. .mytable{padding:10px; background-color:#eee;} , So when i run this and i havn't put any border property there so if it runs and when the client's table tag has a border:1px solid green in it then it will refected in my css..let's say table{border: 1px solid green} which in the client's css then it is reflecting in my css. how could i overcome this issue ?

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, you would have to add `.mytable {border: 0}`. This is just the same "cascade" as it would be if you were overriding styles in your own CSS

Comment: So then i need to write all possible css property to the class to avoid those clashes in the client's css. There are around 300 properties so i need to write those 300 properties to every class to avoid the clash. :O and also use !important too.

Comment: Well, hopefully you don't have to override them *all*. But yes, if you need to remove a style that's been applied, you have to add a style that resets it. If you do a bunch of work for this client, it might be worth coming up with a "reset-the-client-styles.css" stylesheet. If you can wrap everything you add in a `<div class="override-the-client>...</div>` then your reset styesheet could include rules like `.override-the-client table {border: 0}`

Comment: Thank you so much for the kind reply. I get it. :)

Comment: Cool! And while you were reading my comment I updated my answer to include examples of reseting

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the style-loader in your css loader? Look into the rendered DOM and compare the position from the client-css and your react-css. I suspect the react css is inserted as a style tag before the client-css link tag.

Use the [extract-text-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to generate a separat css file, which you can insert into your DOM after the client's css by hand.